# How to use sha256 in c++ from cryptopp

Tags: c++, sha256, pycrypto

First of all thank you for reading my question.

I am trying to reproduce what i recieved in python. So bsically I have two numbers and I am trying to make a hash out of them. But with crypto++ library i am a bit confused.

Basically I dont get how to use the update and calculate part.

My `codes` are

```
    vHash(uint8_t *X,uint8_t *Y)
{
    CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
    byte digest[ CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE ];

    hash.CalculateDigest( digest, (byte*) X, 32 );
    hash.CalculateDigest( digest, (byte*) y, 32 );


    CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
    std::string output;
    encoder.Attach( new CryptoPP::StringSink( output ) );
    encoder.Put( digest, sizeof(digest) );
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    std::cout << output << std::endl;

}
```

and from **main function** i am passing

```
std::string expTA = "67950298974562277680845951570422977358023181305748156081323854942335052287978";
std::string expTB = "43115149028018416730354385099369257625840461867770683759285196743048111210215";

HexDecoder decoder;
decoder.Put((byte*)&exp1[0], expTA.size());
decoder.MessageEnd();

Integer testA;
testA.Decode(decoder, decoder.MaxRetrievable());

HexDecoder decoder1;
decoder1.Put((byte*)&exp1[0], expTB.size());
decoder1.MessageEnd();

Integer testB;
testB.Decode(decoder1, decoder1.MaxRetrievable());


vHash((uint8_t *)&(testA),(uint8_t *)&(testB));
```

Comment: your inputs are very different, in python you have large numbers converted to big endian bytes, in c++ you have the ascii representation of that number

Comment: No I thought Integer from pycrypto++ takes care of that. As i have used other things in python and c++. Its working as expected. If my assumption is wrong please tell me what is the right manner of doing that. Thank You

Comment: ah, I didn't spot that you were performing conversions, you are using `HexDecoder` but your strings aren't hex, I doubt simply casting `testA` and `testB` to pointers will do what you want either

Comment: Looks like passing your strings directly to `Integer` will work: https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html#aa5f24aab6821fe59b7b161682b9a40cd

Comment: Thank You as I mentioned that not the problem. I believe problem is somewhere inside vHash function as it should calculate sha256 in right manner but couldnt find any example regarding it lol.

Comment: use https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html#af7f7a3d1250efd10d84d51ba53297535 to get the bytes from `Integer`. If you're passing incorrect values to `vHash` then you'll never get the correct hash back from it

Comment: see https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SHA2 for a SHA256 example

Comment: So, I need to pass Integer instead of pointer to calculate sha256 ? the example shown are not much useful in my case

Comment: @AlanBirtles this function require pointer byte type
virtual void HashTransformation::CalculateDigest ( byte *  digest,
const byte *  input,
size_t  length 
)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank You Its Solved. You were right I Got confused between hex and decimal. When passing decimal I was thinking I am passing Hex. But its done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I am pasting it here So that it may be useful for someone else.

For calculating right sha256 first to update and then call the calculate function in the manner mentioned below.

```
hash.Update((byte*) X, 32 );
hash.CalculateDigest( digest, (byte*) y, 32 );
```

This is optional but to make sure what we are comparing with than be sure to enter eiher the int values or hex values ur answer will be generated in that manner. i.e. std::string expTA.